# How to check if element with ID exists in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jqlite

How can I check if an element with a specific ID already exists in my DOM inside an Angular directive? By using `angular.element()` an element is created if one does not exist, for example `angular.element('someID')` will return an element whether one already exist or not.

What I am doing now as a workaround is using the `.html()` jqLite function like this:

> if(angular.element('#someElementID').**html()**) {
>
> > console.log('only fires if element already exists');
>
> }

Is there a better way to do this? I would like to avoid including the whole jQuery just for this.

Comment: Did you try angular.element($document).find('#someElementID') ?

Comment: No, but I did now. Same result, creates an object.

Comment: I just tried that in the console, both angular.element($document).find('#someElementID') and angular.element('#someElementID') return an empty array.
You should be pretty safe doing the following:
if ( angular.element('#someElementID').length ) {
  console.log('#someElementID exists');
}

Comment: True it's an array, thanks for pointing it out. Feel free to post an answer otherwise I'll do it later to close the question.

Comment: The Angular documentation (which I find quite poor by the way) added to my confusion since it mentions that `angular.element()` returns a jQuery object and not an array: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Both angular.element($document).find('#someElementID') and angular.element('#someElementID') return an empty array, in case several dom nodes matched the selector.

You should be pretty safe doing the following:

```
if ( angular.element('#someElementID').length ) {
    console.log('#someElementID exists');
}
```

Also keep in mind that jQLite .find() method only supports tag names.

Comment: Could you please add an example with real data? It's because I don't know how is "angula.element" related to my code.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested, its working fine..

**If the ID is Exists, it return 1**

**ID is not Exists, it return 0**

```
if(angular.element('#someElementID').length >0){
 console.log("Id is available.");
}else{
  console.log("Id is not available.");
}
```